# Suitecrm call Module Builder through shell script

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am kind of new to SuiteCRM; I want to install a module through Module Builder.

Essentially I want to call the method that executes when deploy button is hit in SuiteCRM Module Builder. I am uploading my package through git and want to automate the process of deploy which can be triggered by a shell script.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a custom entrypoint, you use curl in script to call the entrypoint.

In the entrypoint you would need to include the classes used in modules/ModuleBuilder/MB to deploy the module.

The rest of the implementation is up to you.